# Measure value not visible on the dashboard widget

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins, sonarqube

I am a newbie in sonar and trying to code a plugin.While trying to work with the standard sample plugin that is available, I could print the value stored in the'random' metric but that of the 'message' metric is not visible on the dashboard widget. Also the key for the this metric was 'message_key' in SampleMetrics and 'message' in the widget's erb file. I changed them to be same but still it is not visible. But if I try to display the description of both the metrics, both are visible. 
Here is the required code:

In SampleMetrics file:

```
 public static final Metric MESSAGE = new Metric("message", "Message",
    "This is a metric to store a well known message", Metric.ValueType.STRING, -1, false,
    CoreMetrics.DOMAIN_GENERAL);


  public static final Metric RANDOM = new Metric("random", "Random",
    "Random value", Metric.ValueType.FLOAT, Metric.DIRECTION_BETTER, false,
    CoreMetrics.DOMAIN_GENERAL);

*
```

In SampleSensor file:

```
public class SampleSensor implements Sensor {

  public boolean shouldExecuteOnProject(Project project) {
    // this sensor is executed on any type of project
    return true;
  }

  public void analyse(Project project, SensorContext sensorContext) {
    saveLabelMeasure(sensorContext);
    saveNumericMeasure(sensorContext);
  }

  private void saveNumericMeasure(SensorContext context) {
    // Sonar API includes many libraries like commons-lang and google-collections
    context.saveMeasure(SampleMetrics.RANDOM, RandomUtils.nextDouble());
  }

  private void saveLabelMeasure(SensorContext context) {
    Measure measure = new Measure(SampleMetrics.MESSAGE, "Hello World!");
    context.saveMeasure(measure);
  }
}
```

In sample_dashboard_widget.html.erb file :

```
<div class="dashbox">
  <h3><span><%= metric('message').description -%></span></h3>
  <h3><span><%= metric('random').description -%></span></h3>
  <p>
    <span class="big">
      <%= format_measure('random') -%> <%= tendency_icon(measure('random')) %>
    </span>
  </p>
  <p><%= format_measure('message') -%></p>
</div>
```

Can anybody suggest me what step I am missing in getting the message metric's measure value printed on the widget?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this with my own test-widget and had no problems at all:

```
<p><%= format_measure('my_key') -%></p>
```

Showed the string value of the metric. I couldn't find any error in your code example. Are you sure the metrics is written?
Take a look in the logs and maybe add some log-output.

You can also show the metric value with this:

```
<%= @snapshot.measure('my_key').formatted_value  -%>
```